# I can't understand why scan does not work at this code

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, calculator

I just started to code for fun and tried to make a basic calculator,
but I got a problem.

There is my code at the bottom

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class practice {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double temp1, temp2;
    int temp4 = 1;
    int end = 0;
    **String temp3,temp5;**
    calculator cal = new calculator();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);


    while(end==0){
    System.out.println("Please put your first number to calculate");
    temp1 = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Please put your second number to calculate");
    temp2 = scan.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("What arithmetic operation you want to do?(+,-,/,*)");

    **temp3 = scan.nextLine();**

    if(temp3.equals("+")){
        System.out.println("Result is" + cal.add(temp1, temp2));
    }

    else if(temp3.equals("-")){
        System.out.println("Result is" + cal.subtract(temp1, temp2));
    }

    else if(temp3.equals("*")){
        System.out.println("Result is" + cal.multiply(temp1, temp2));
    }

    else if(temp3.equals("/")){
        System.out.println("Result is" + cal.divide(temp1, temp2));
    }
    else
        System.out.println("You got wrong operator");

    while(temp4==1){
        System.out.println("Now you want to quit(press y/n)");
        temp5 = scan.nextLine();

        if(temp5.equals("y")){
            temp4=0;
            end=1;
        }

        else if(temp5.equals("n")){
            System.out.println("Then here we go again");
            temp4=0;
        }

        else
            System.out.println("You put wrong words");
        }
    }
}
}
```

---

I can't understand why temp3 didn't work.

I wanted to check I made mistake, so I made temp5 but it works.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: does this code compile?  Why don't you try pringitn out the value of temp3?  This is called debugging

Comment: it's compiled. Sorry, I just saw this one. I actually did, and I made another variable called temp5 because I thought temp3 didn't work because it used twice(that was quite stupid thou). And it didn't work still and I asked through this site :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `nextDouble()` doesn't use up the new line character used when entering the second `double`.  So `nextLine()` sees the newline already present and consumes it.

Add in an extra `nextLine()` call to consume the newline from the second number.

```
temp2 = scan.nextDouble();

// Add consuming of new line here.
String dummy = scan.nextLine();

System.out.println("What arithmetic operation you want to do?(+,-,/,*)");

temp3 = scan.nextLine();
```

Comment: I tried and it works. can you tell me how does it work? I mean why that 2nd nexDouble didn't used?